# Xcode 4.3: Codesign operation failed (Check that the identity you selected is valid)

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, codesign

After installing Xcode 4.3 I can't validate and distribute application using Organizer.
While building, signing and validating in Xcode is OK, the validation in Organizer fails with the message in the title of this question.

First, Xcode 4.3 can download provisioning profiles automatically (there's an option in Organizer), but it downloads only development profiles and ignores distribution profiles as if there are none. OK, I downloaded and installed it manually and it appears in Organizer. Then I set proper Code Signing Identity both for project and for target and use Distribution profile that matches Distribution certificate in my keychain. Then I do Archive (build-sign-verify) and no errors, in the log I see green checkmarks for CodeSign and for Verify steps. Looks good and the archive appears in Organizer.

And that's where all goes wrong, I just select Validate, choose the new version I just prepared in iTunes Connect, choose correct code signing identity, same as was used for Archiving (actually, there are no other choices in my case), it asks for iTunes login/password as usual, and then says

> Codesign operation failed
>
> Check that the identity you selected is valid

Ahhh!!! Why!? It had no problems while archiving it, then same code signing doesn't work when trying to submit to AppStore. Well, not even submit, but validate before actually sending it. So this issue is local to my machine. The very same signing and validation that is successful during build, fails in Organizer...

I tried everything, re-installed Xcode, removed/revoked and re-issued all certificates, removed duplicated private and public keys from keychain, put all certificates in one "login" keychain, issued new profiles, installed Application Loader 2.5.1, and so on... still no luck.

Could it be that I have some left-over from previous Xcode installs? Or that I have to update some tools to make Organizer work properly?

Meanwhile, if anyone knows another way to upload binary to AppStore, please share. I couldn't figure out how to do that using Application Loader, when it asks me to choose a bundle to upload, all I have is xcode archive created by Xcode in Archive step. How do I get my hands on iap or whatever file the Application Loader wants from me?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Are you using addThis in your application? I found this and wanted to confirm. https://devforums.apple.com/message/621193#621193

Comment: Yes, I do use addThis in the app!  Due to my stupidity I kinda "hot swapped" the battery and damaged file system on HDD. I ended up installing Snow Leopard and Xcode 4.2 and the app was signed/validated with no errors. Then I upgraded to Lion and Xcode 4.3 and again - validation error.  Just now I tried to get iap for ad-hoc distribution of another app from another developer account - no errors, and this app doesn't use AddThis.  So this must be AddThis, I'm going to go to their website and see if they've posted updated SDK for Xcode 4.3.

Comment: just got latest 0.1.7 addthis sdk version - same error.

Comment: Got the same problem, but when I was installing Xcode 4.3 I didn't removed the installation of Xcode 4.2.1 so I just opened my app with that version of Xcode and everything was ok.

By other side I wasted 2 days of my life with this stupid Xcode bug.

Answer (score 31):

I've discovered that Xcode 4.3.1 has a serious issue validating apps with resources within a directory tree within an application bundle.

Apps can pass validation within the Xcode "Build for Archive" process - it only fails when the validation is run via Organizer.

After spending hours trying to trace down the usual code signing entitlement issues, I eventually noticed the following line in the system console when the export fails:

*3/10/12 2:32:48.450 PM [0x0-0x261261].com.apple.dt.Xcode: /Users/chris/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-03-10/Coverage 3-10-12 2.32 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Coverage.app/Tiles/T-Mobile-roam/4: Is a directory*

I spent a day trying to isolate this bug, and I've finally nailed it.

The code signer in XCode 4.3.1 when validating for the App Store or saving for AdHoc distribution chokes whenever there is a subdirectory in your bundle that has the same name as its parent directory.

For example:

```
test/test/file.x -- FAIL
test/test2/file.x -- WORKS
```

This seems to be new in Xcode 4.3.1, and hopefully will be fixed soon.

Notes: This thread seems related: https://devforums.apple.com/message/630800

Comment: Thanks for doing this investigation - I was having the same problem and there turned out to be two folders like this. After renaming/removing them it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem. Very, very frustrating.

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time with this answer, thank you!! I also had a Tiles directory that was causing the issue. I went in and changed one of the sets of folders to start with an underscore, then stripped that underscore in the code when reading the folder's names to use for tile placement.

Comment: Thanks :) Helped me a lot. Problem still appears in 4.3.3 (4E3002).

Comment: Problem (STILL) exists in Xcode 4.6.  Just had to do rename a folder to sidestep it here on our side as well.

Answer (score 8):

I was the original poster on the Apple Dev Forums...
https://devforums.apple.com/message/621193

I've also attempted to bring this to the attention of the AddThis developers:
https://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=38292

As mentioned in the other posts, the only way I've found to prevent the code signing failure is to remove the ATResources.bundle file from the project.

Of course, this bundle contains many of the necessary images for AddThis, among other things, but the error no longer occurs.

I'm hoping this helps someone else discover the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi. I think the only correct way would be to get an update from AddThis devs or some fix from Apple if that's Xcode 4.3 bug.  However, there's a work around which looks ok and works for me. I notices that ATResources bundle has 3 items inside  - ADDTHIS.db  - en.lproj folder with Localizable.strings  - images folder with 6 images  I just copied all these files from the bundle (used _Show Package Contents_ to get inside) and added them to my project instead of ATResources.bundle.  It all built without errors, all the images came up properly in AddThis UI and no signing error too.

Comment: Some update, the solution in my post above does not seem fix the problem. The app seems to work fine, probably because ADDTHIS.db is copied to cache folder of the app. If you remove an app and then install again built using recommendations in my post, the list of social networks will be empty in the app.

Comment: As radven pointed out, the problem appears to be that there is a folder within the bundle with the _same name_ as the bundle.  I renamed the offending folder by appending an underscore and my app signs and the library in question still seems to display the list of services properly.

Comment: Hi Joe. Just tried your solution and it works. I was sure to wipe old version before testing, and even more - reset simulator and delete project derived data.

Comment: Joe, why don't you post this solution as an answer?
So far this is the easiest fix of all. Just rename the folder, no hassle with trying to get rid of the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is AddThis or explicitly the ATResources.bundle in the AddThis folder.

So you have two options:

- The first one is using an older version of Xcode to Archive.
- The second one is relocate all the images inside the
  ATResources.bundle into a folder, and copy the content of the
  Localizable.strings into your own Localizable.strings

  Then open the FBDialog.m file and search for "close.png", remove that
  line of code and replace it with:

  UIImage* closeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"];

Now you're ready to Archive.

Finally consider to file a bug report in https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 2):

[In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10830989/43615), it was a damaged custom framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have so many subdirectories on my bundle that have the same name as their parents, so I was not able to validate and submit. The only solution I found is to download xcode 4.2.1 from Apple developer center and install it side by side with xcode 4.3.2. Then I used it to validate and submit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing on Sencha 2. The key here is to launch the System Console from Apps/Utilities and look at the error log when distributing. That's the easiest way to see the offending directory. In Sencha2 its in the /sdk/src/device/device. Good stuff: Still happening in xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Just confirming that the problem was indeed nested folders with the same name in my app.

In my particular case this was the issue:

- problem:  images/packs/**1/1**/img.png
- solution: images/packs/**pack_1/1**/img.png

Smooth sailing after that. This happened in Xcode 4.3.3

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in my project (in xcode 4.3.2) and as per all answers I checked for any `.png` file starting with `._*` and also checked folder and its subfolder are different name.

Also checked *code signing identity* as per requirement, but did not succeed to solve this problem.

After whole days effort finally I got reason for "Packaging operation failed" error in my project.

In my case, I have classed `About_us.h` and `About_us.m` and by mistake I import header file like  `#import "About Us.h"` (white space in middle). So when I loaded app on Device it will successfully loaded but when I try to create *ipa* using archive its give me error and return me Estimated App Store Size just 143 kb.

Finally while I change header like  `#import "About_Us.h"` and try to make *ipa* I got real size in proper MB.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution, it really works for me. hope this will help you guys.

if the issue is because of Addthis, try following

[image]

noted that the inside ATResources.bundle you have a folder named ATResources.

ATResources contains exactly the copy items (ADDTHIS.db,en.lproj,images) which is present in ATResources.bundle. so we can simply delete the ATResources folder from ATResources.bundle.

for deleting,, select the files from ATResources.bundle and right click , show in finder -> and remove ATResources folder.

[image]

the major issue is because subdirectory in your bundle that has the same name as its parent directory.

:)

Comment: This solution will fail you later, this is one of the first approaches I tried. Delete an app from device/simulator completely, then install new build fixed this way. In my case the list of social networks in AddThis UI was empty, that made id useless.

The best and the easiest solution so far is to rename ATResources to _ATResources or anything other, different from original name. Rename it right there in Xcode. It will build, link, get signed and no issues with missing social networks.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue on Xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005) with 2 completely separate folders that happened to be named the same thing.

Most other cases in this thread focus on the parent/sibling relationship, but I think it's any  two folders with the same name will cause this failure.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you do, and radven response inspired me:

did you see that ATResources directory contains nothing more than just copy of its parent?

```
ADDTHIS.db
en.lproj/*
images/*
ATResources/ADDTHIS.db
ATResources/en.lproj/*
ATResources/images/*
```

As a quick-and-dirty fix I removed the redundant subdirectory. Application builds and seems to work fine, and Xcode is able to sign.

Let me know if I missed any consequence of this fix?

Comment: I tried that fix and first thought it was working. But days after release to App Store, some users reported that list of social networks in AddThis is empty. I think the ADDTHIS.db has list of all networks and is cached on device and simulator, so testing right after removing ATResources looked OK, because previous version has cached the file. After a while or on a fresh install, the file is missing and AddThis is rendered useless. Try to reset simulator or remove app from device, then try to run it again and see if it works before sending it for review.

Comment: Have a look at Joe Ibanez's comment above. Renaming ATResources folder to _ATResources inside ATResources.bundle did the trick for me. I able to sign an app now with Xcode 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Gee, I spent like an hour on this problem.

I just removed AddThis from my project. Do it and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

restarting xcode made the buttons work for me. they were greyed out before, in case anyone here is having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Techi50 alluded to this but to be clear - under Xcode 4.3.5 there is a serious bug where code signing will fail if you have subdirectories with the same name as the parent directory.  In the Sencha Touch 2 SDK tree, for example, there is

/sdk/src/device/device

argh... hours of trying to code sign with no luck... rename to:

/sdk/src/device/device_epic_fail

(since I don't need those libraries anyway)

and I can code sign.

And one big bug hunt is over.  Apple... fix please...

Answer (score 0):

Updating the AddThis SDK from 0.1.7 to 0.1.9 fixed this problem for me (using XCode 4.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

I've determined another cause of this error, which occurred for me in Xcode 4.6.2 (4H1003).  I had a subproject building an executable.  This executable is a helper tool which is copied into my app's bundle when it builds.

The app has a min deployment target of OS X 10.7 and builds for 64-bit Intel as a result.
The helper tool, however, was set to a deployment target of 10.6, and was building for 32-bit/64-bit Intel.

Changing the helper tool to also build for 10.7 and 64-bit Intel only fixed the error.  I can reliably recreate the error by changing the helper tool back to 32-bit/64-bit Intel; this is not a 'erm, zap your PRAM' fix.

Answer (score 0):

As @radven and @tomek-cejner mentioned sometimes some extra directories could cause problems. Maybe if named improperly? for me the offenders were different.

> Gruntfile.js, karma-e2e.conf.js, karma.conf.js, and the entire node_modules directory.

see: [How to build IPA for distribution with TestFlight with XCode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109616/1449799)