# (null): In section __TEXT,__text reloc 3: section For Address(0x7C6C) address not in any section for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode

After upgrading to Xcode 4.4 I am getting this annoying linker error when trying to run my (universal) app on the iPhone or iPad. I have no problems if I run it on the iOS Simulator though...
I tried adding armv6, and excluding armv7, but no luck...
Any idea?

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt everything?  Does it use any external static libraries?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just wanted to say thanks for the question and your answer, niraj! I had the same problem and the solution worked perfectly.

To save people some translation time, the answer is to set "Generate Position-Dependent Code" to "No" in the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 - Code Generation" section of your target's "Build Settings".

Answer (score 2):

After wasting three hours on it, I finally found one useful post in a Chinese blog that solved my problem!!! Here is the link:

http://blog.k-res.net/%E8%AE%BE%E8%AE%A1%E5%BC%80%E5%8F%91/%E5%8D%87%E7%BA%A7xcode-4-4%E5%90%8E%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AEbuild%E6%8F%90%E7%A4%BAaddress-section-architecture-armv7%E7%9A%84%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95.html

Comment: The link no longer exists