# App Store Submission, Validation Error

Tags: ios, app-store

I've been trying to submit a new application to App Store for the past 17 hours or so.  It's not the first one to submit.  If I click on the **Distribute** button on the **Organizer** window to submit a binary to **App Store**, I get an error message that says **Application failed code sign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate**.  I've read a dozen topics regarding this error.  What I have so far is

[image]

1. I have the right distribution certificate.
2. The build configuration is set to 'Release.'
3. I have no entitlements to begin with, by the way.
4. The right code signing identity as well as the application are selected.  Plus, I have the right username and password to connect iTunes Connect.
5. I've downloaded and reinstalled the distribution certificate for the application in question.
6. I've even created a new App ID and a bundle identifier to submit this application under a different name.  And I get the same validation error.

Do you have any idea as to what I am doing wrong?  I've run out of choices.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985320/code-signing-error-application-failed-codesign-verification#

Comment: I already went through that topic yesterday.  Thanks.

Comment: The only aspect of this project different from more than a dozen that I've worked on for the first several months is that I import a whole directory by choosing 'Create folder references for any added folders.'  Perhaps, that's the cause?  The following topic seems to suggest my hunch.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649859/xcode-4-3-1-breaks-validation-of-apps-with-directories-added-by-reference-any-w

Comment: I'm right.  If I remove the direct directory, validation passes.  It's not my fault.  Fix it, Apple!

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  The solution is to remove garbage files.  I used a terminal command as described in the following link.  https://superuser.com/questions/319553/mac-terminal-script-to-remove-hidden-files