# iOS Add a certificate to an existing distribution profile

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am trying to upload a new version of our application to the app store, however Xcode tells me I don't have a valid identity to sign with.

I've looked into the distribution profile and found that indeed only our company certificate is connected with this distribution profile. I need to add my personal certificate to this distribution profile, but I've not been able to find a way to do this.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

EDIT: Actually, it doesn't look like my certificate is a DISTRIBUTION certificate anyway. I suppose I'd actually need to create a new distribution certificate? Is it possible to change an existing developer certificate to also be a distribution certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a certificate to Existing Distribution or Provisioning Profile .. !! You must either

- Download the original certificate the one with which the Profile is Associated OR
- Create Distribution Profiles for Your Developer Certificate - the one you currently have.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do you create a Distribution Profile for my developer certificate? I can't seem to find a way to do that...

Comment: In the Developer Provisioning Portal, there is a tab called Provisioning to left. There you'll find a tab called distribution. Create AppStore or Adhoc Distribution profile for your AppID for given certificate.

Comment: Ah, I misread your answer and therefore asked the wrong question. What I meant to say is how can I create a Distribution Certificate?

Comment: it is relatively lengthy process.. this video might help. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofoj1DbU1GU

Answer (score 0):

Me also faced same error log from Xcode 4.3 on uploading second version of build to app store.

Then I used old version of Xcode to upload build and successfully uploaded. Here is similar post that helped me.

[Xcode 4.3: Codesign operation failed (Check that the identity you selected is valid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386925/xcode-4-3-codesign-operation-failed-check-that-the-identity-you-selected-is-va)