# Xcode 4.3.3: Codesign operation failed: Check that the identity you signed is valid

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, distribution, codesign

I already messed up with the "iOS no identities are available for signing" and there was a simple solution, just to get a developer profile. However I just ran into another problem before submitting my app. I looked all over and tried others solutions such as: [Xcode 4.3: Codesign operation failed (Check that the identity you selected is valid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386925/xcode-4-3-codesign-operation-failed-check-that-the-identity-you-selected-is-va)

Didn't work, any help at all now would be appreciated, because I'm on the border of just screaming out in frustration at distributing this app, because honestly everything leading up to it was a lot easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the profiles from your iOS Provisioning Portal. Recreate the profile. In Xcode, hit refresh in your organizer -> devices. Clean the project and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to revoke and recreate the certificate/provisioning profile... Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue, and it's not solved by @Ninja's sugestion above, try removing extraneous files. For me they were:

> Gruntfile.js, karma-e2e.conf.js, karma.conf.js, and the entire node_modules directory.

see: [How to build IPA for distribution with TestFlight with XCode 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25109616/1449799)